# How to handle an error by exiting a nested loop?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to prepare mail items while some mails are supposed to have more than one attachment.

I want my `On Error GoTo chyba` to jump to the `Next i` when there is an error.

```
Sub novy_mail()

    Dim attachments(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As String
        prilohy(1, 1) = "subor1.txt"
        prilohy(1, 2) = "subor2.txt"
        prilohy(2, 1) = "subor2.txt"
        prilohy(2, 2) = "subor3.txt"
        prilohy(3, 1) = "subor3.txt"
        prilohy(3, 2) = "subor4.txt"
        prilohy(4, 1) = "subor4.txt"
        prilohy(5, 1) = "subor5.txt"

    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To UBound(attachments, 1)
        Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With oMsg
            For j = 1 To UBound(attachments, 2)
                On Error GoTo chyba
                .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" + attachments(i, j)
            Next j   
            .Display
        End With
chyba:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? What happens and what should happen? An errors?

Comment: When    prilohy(i, j)    is undefined, the code should jump to    chyba:    and stop trying to add new attachments in mail item. What happens is that when inner loop tries to reach for prilohy(i, j) which is undefined, it shows error.

Comment: Which array is the real one - attachments or prilohy ?

Comment: Instead of check for error, check for file exist! A websearch for "vba file exists" will show you how-to.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. This may result in consistent array naming. Investigate how to set up the VB editor to add `Option Explicit` by default to force variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `On Error Resume Next` and a check of the `Error.Number` after the statement to skip the loop. Skipping works by setting the loop counter so that the loop terminates.

Don't forget to re-enable the regular error handling by setting `On Error Goto 0`, otherwise your program will begin to behave strangely.

```
Sub novy_mail()
    Dim attachments(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    prilohy(1, 1) = "subor1.txt"
    prilohy(1, 2) = "subor2.txt"
    prilohy(2, 1) = "subor2.txt"
    prilohy(2, 2) = "subor3.txt"
    prilohy(3, 1) = "subor3.txt"
    prilohy(3, 2) = "subor4.txt"
    prilohy(4, 1) = "subor4.txt"
    prilohy(5, 1) = "subor5.txt"

    For i = 1 To UBound(attachments, 1)
        With Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            For j = 1 To UBound(attachments, 2)
                On Error Resume Next
                .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" + prilohy(i, j)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then j = UBound(attachments, 2)
                On Error Goto 0
            Next j   
            .Display
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that the `oMsg` variable can made superfluous.

---

A way to make this nicer to use is to extract the part of your code that you expect to fail into a separate function:

```
Sub novy_mail()
    Dim attachments(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As String
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    prilohy(1, 1) = "subor1.txt"
    prilohy(1, 2) = "subor2.txt"
    prilohy(2, 1) = "subor2.txt"
    prilohy(2, 2) = "subor3.txt"
    prilohy(3, 1) = "subor3.txt"
    prilohy(3, 2) = "subor4.txt"
    prilohy(4, 1) = "subor4.txt"
    prilohy(5, 1) = "subor5.txt"

    For i = 1 To UBound(attachments, 1)
        Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        For j = 1 To UBound(attachments, 2)
            If TryAddAttachment(oMsg, "C:\Users\" + prilohy(i, j)) Then
                oMsg.Display
            Else
                j = UBound(attachments, 2)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function TryAddAttachment(mail As Outlook.MailItem, path As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    mail.Attachments.Add path
    TryAddAttachment = (Err.Number = 0)
    ' "On Error" is automatically reset when the function ends
End Function
```

---

Personally, I would try and avoid working with multi-dimensional arrays here. It's just not nice in VBA. I'd also create a function that only creates a single mail and call that multiple times:

```
Sub create_mails()
    novy_mail "C:\Users\subor1.txt|C:\Users\subor2.txt"
    novy_mail "C:\Users\subor2.txt|C:\Users\subor3.txt"
    novy_mail "C:\Users\subor3.txt|C:\Users\subor4.txt"
    novy_mail "C:\Users\subor4.txt"
    novy_mail "C:\Users\subor5.txt"
End Sub

Function novy_mail(attachments As String) As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim path As Variant

    Set novy_mail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each path In Split(attachments, "|")
        If Not TryAddAttachment(oMsg, path) Then Exit For
        oMail.Display
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the error handler if it already caught an error `on error goto 0`.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(attachments, 1)
    Set oMsg = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oMsg
        For j = 1 To UBound(attachments, 2)
            On Error GoTo chyba
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" + attachments(i, j)
        Next j   
        .Display
    End With

chyba:

    ' can be used whether an error has been caught or not
    on error goto 0

Next i
```

You will want to comment `On Error GoTo chyba` and test where there are no expected errors. Once you fix any unexpected errors, uncomment.